# Show tr according to what is typed into search box

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/YxU2H/2/
This is an example of what I'm trying to do. Hide the row according to what is typed into the box. For some reason the keyup is not working like it should. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var search$ = $('#search'),
        table$ = $('#attribute'),
        content = '';
    search$.keyup(function() {
        var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
        if (val === content) { // this.value gives the types value
            return;
        }
        content = val;
        table$.find('tbody>tr').show();
        table$.find('tbody h4').filter(function(index, element) {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(content) === -1;
        }).closest('tr').hide();
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YxU2H/9/)**

Comment: That was indeed quick and it works but it's hiding the header of the table. how do prevent that?